# Difference between <%= form_tag and <% form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having a problem in Rails .. I might be a silly question, but pls give me suggestions.

What is the difference between:

```
  <%= form_tag("path", :method=>'post') do %>
  <% end %>
```

and:

```
  <% form_tag("path", :method=>'post') do %>
  <% end %>
```

Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They do the same thing. The former is the Rails 3 syntax, the latter targets Rails versions < 3.

Rails 3 still support the syntax without the leading equal but it currently prints a deprecation warning. The Rails 2 syntax will be removed in Rails 3.1.

Comment: You probably meant Rails < 3? :)